# I can't use the full buffer viewport in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open my terminal in Visual Studio Code, I can't use half the buffer viewport on the screen. I am presented with half the buffer viewport for working in the terminal.

[image: Example of there terminal I see]

It was working until I got a message from VS Code telling me that my terminal is running slower than usual and that I can use a DOM version instead. (I can't recall the wording exactly) I chose to try it.

It worked fine for a while and then it jumped to the middle of the viewport which makes the top part unusable.

I don't know what information to give but I am running Fedora 28, VS Code 1.30.2, the experience is the same on both **Integrated** and **External** Explorer Kind terminals. I have **gnome-terminal** selected as my Linux Exec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably ended up setting the terminal renderType to DOM.

1. Go to settings ( COMMAND (⌘) + COMMA (,) or use the Command Palette to search for settings).
2. Then search for `terminal.integrated.rendererType` and make sure it is set to `auto`

— A more detailed explanation can be [found here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_changing-how-the-terminal-is-rendered).

> Helpful gif if I may:

[image: VSCode terminal render type]

Comment: Yip, that fixed it. I can't believe I overlooked that setting. Thank you so much!